# I need a function that takes a list as input, but returns none and changes the input in the following ways:

Tags: python

- Strings have all their letters converted to upper-case
- Integers and floats have their value increased by 1
- booleans are negated (False becomes True, True becomes False)
- Lists are replaced with the word ”List”

The problem I'm encountering is that we're changing the list itself instead if making a copy to return.
Here is what I have done so far:

```
def mutate_me(my_list):
'''(list)-> NoneType
returns my_list mutated the same way
as the function copy_me

>>>test_list = [1, 2.5, "1abc", [1, 2, 3], False]
>>>mutate_me(test_list)
>>>test_list = [2, 3.5, "1ABC", "List", True]

>>>test_list = [2, False, ["list"], "Hello", 1.0]
>>>mutate_me(test_list)
>>>test_list = [3, True, "List", "HELLO", 2.0]
'''
# go through every element in the list
# check there type and based upon there
# type apply the rule
for element in my_list:
    if(type(element) == str):
        for i in element:
            if(i.isalpha()):
                element = element.upper()
        my_list.append(element)
    elif(type(element) == int or type(element) == float):
        element = element + 1
    elif(type(element) == bool):
        element = not element
    elif(type(element) == list):
        element = "List"
    else:
        element
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def mutate_me(my_list):
    for idx, element in enumerate(my_list):
        if(type(element) == str):
            my_list[idx] = element.upper()
        elif(type(element) == int or type(element) == float):
            my_list[idx] = element + 1
        elif(type(element) == bool):
            my_list[idx] = not element
        elif(type(element) == list):
            my_list[idx] = "List"
```

Comment: OP does not want to return,  but mutate the input

Comment: this is not changing the original list but my question is how can I change the original list its one of things I need to understand and I can't wrap my head around.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small sample of the solution

```
for i, element in enumerate(my_list):
    if(type(element) == str):
        my_list[i] = element.upper()
```

You need enumerate to mutate while iterating

Comment: I believe the OP explicitly told "The problem I'm encountring is that we're changing the list itself instead if making a copy"

Comment: Exactly. The problem is changing the list itself **instead of** making a copy

Comment: @Art OP clarified the issue himself in one of the comments, I also misunderstood the question, but this answer is right, OP wanted to modify the list in-place.